# How can I handle high cardinal/sparse features using neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, sparse-matrix

I look for examples about encoding high cardinal or sparse datasets using Neural Networks but I cannot find it. Also I search about embedding numerical variables (not categorical) however I couldn't find any examples either. Can you send me a GitHub link etc. if you have about these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Working with neural networks I am assuming that **tensorflow with Keras backend** is being used?

If so here is a reference snippet, main library used [tf.feature_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

feature_columns=[]
for col in list(df_train_numerical.columns):
    col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(col)
    feature_columns.append(col)
    
for col in list(df_train_categorical.columns):
    col = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(col, hash_bucket_size=8000), dimension=8)
    #above hash bucket size is specified (cardinality) with dimension
    feature_columns.append(col)
    
feature_layer = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
```

Following that the **feature_layer** is basically the first layer of the neural network-

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(feature_layer)
```

[reference git code](https://github.com/AgnijDave/logisticRegressionDeepLearning/blob/d893088d6d5f730f80d7f19c50db964bd6b5043e/main.py#L178)